# Trading hours in strategy

Tags: pine-script

How can I tell a tradingview strategy to only trade during regular trading hours, ie 0930 to 1600? I don't know why, but my "if" statements always return errors. eg. if (xxx > yyy) do this

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do using session information. The usrman has a page on [handling sessions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html) and allanster shows how to use session information to limit strat orders [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/xAEG4ZJG-How-To-Set-Backtest-Time-Ranges/).